# Select jQuery by CSS attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select an image by the CSS that is automatically applied through a CMS to that image and then add a class. Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.pageBody p img').css('float') === 'right') {
        $('.pageBody p img').addClass('float-right');
    }
});
```

That script works just fine with an image that has `float: right` applied. There is another image that has `float: left` applied. The problem is, if I switch "right" to "left" in the script than it wont' work. For example, if I have an image set to `float: left` and use this script than it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.pageBody p img').css('float') === 'left') {
        $('.pageBody p img').addClass('float-left');
    }
});
```

Comment: If it works with `right`, and not `left`, are you sure it actually has that style applied.

Comment: Is the other image inside a tag with the pageBody class wrapped inside a p tag?

Comment: Can you print out the CSS value by doing something like `console.log($('.pageBody p img').css('float'))`, it should give you enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code will only work if the image you're interested in is the first one in the document. You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to locate that image regardless of its position in the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pageBody p img").filter(function() {
        return $(this).css("float") == "left";
    }).addClass("float-left");
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the form of [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) that takes a function to add `float-left` or `float-right` classes to all the images depending on the value of their `float` style:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pageBody p img").addClass(function() {
        var direction = $(this).css("float");
        if (direction == "left" || direction == "right") {
            return "float-" + direction;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the help. I can't accept your answer for seven minutes but as soon as I can I will.

Comment: or wack it with each: `return ($(this).css("float") == "left" || $(this).css("float") == "right");
}).each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("float-" + $(this).css("float"));
});`  nice answer btw